# RxSwift extending Observable generic type issue

Tags: swift, generics, reactive-programming, observable

I'm having trouble writing some RxSwift utility function. I want to create a utility function maps multiple `Observable<Bool>` streams to a single `Observable<Bool>` stream, which checks if every source streams are `true`. It can be achieved by the following code.

```swift
var v1 = Variable<Bool>(true)
var v2 = Variable<Bool>(false)

Observable.combineLatest(v1.asObservable(), v2.asObservable()) { (a, b) -> Bool in
    return a && b
    }
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .subscribe(onNext: { v in
        print(">> \(v)")
    })

v1.value = true

// will print
// >> false
// >> true
```

So I wrote the following code.

```swift
import RxSwift

extension Observable {
    public static func every(_ s1: Observable<Bool>, _ s2: Observable<Bool>) -> Observable<Bool> {
        return Observable.combineLatest(s1, s2) { (a, b) -> Bool in
            return a && b
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't compile with error `Declared closure result 'Bool' is incompatible with contextual type '_'`. Tried to fix, but can't get it fixed.

Probably something is gone wrong with generic type system, but I can't figure out. Help would be much appreciated.

====

**Edit**

As @Tomasz Pikć answered, I could make it compile using `Observable<Bool>.combineLatest`. But `every` function could only be called with `Observable<Bool>` like the following.

```
Observable<Bool>.every(r1.asObservable(), r2.asObservable())
    .subscribe(onNext: { (e:Bool) in
        print(">> \(e)")
    })
```

How can I change it to use `Observable.every` instead of `Observable<Bool>.every` like when I use `Observable.combineLatest`?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `<Bool>`

```
extension Observable {
  static func every(_ s1: Observable<Bool>, _ s2: Observable<Bool>) -> Observable<Bool> {
    return Observable<Bool>.combineLatest(s1, s2) { $0 && $1 }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but how can make it available for `Observable.every` instead of `Observable<Bool>.every`?